# D3.js line is returning a random number

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

Prefacing this with the fact I'm new to D3 and it's probably a simple mistake I'm missing - I know it has to be. Something with the way I'm attempting to access the data.

Trying to figure this guy out for a while. (maybe I've looked at it too long)

I played around with it until my line *finally* showed up at all, but now it's not displaying the full line, just two points - that are numbers I'm not sure of.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The goal is to use lineData[0] to plot one line along the x-axis of lineData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APbb7.png) (months). Eventually, lineData[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23JtU.png) will be used for a second line, but just trying to get the first line to work at the moment.

EDIT: Updated code (per Shashank's suggetions) can be found here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RevxYG?editors=0010

My updated graph is looking better, but still seeing NaN values:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
 let lineData = [
    [4, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 52, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1], 
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
  ]
            console.log("lineData", lineData)

        // set dimensions of the line chart
        let width = 393,
            height = 285;


        // set the scales
        let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()    
            .domain([0, 52])
            .range([height - 40 , 0]);

        let xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range([0, width - 40]);

        // create the line
        let line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[0]); });

        // create svg container
        let lineChart = d3.select(element)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("viewbox", "0 60 960 600")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class", "line-chart")

        lineChart.append("path")
            .datum(lineData)
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "rebeccapurple")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)

        lineChart.selectAll("dot")
            .data(lineData)
            .attr("d", line)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 3.5)
            .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(i)})
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[0])})
            .attr("fill", "rebeccapurple")

        lineChart.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20, 245)")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))

        lineChart.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
```

The data is being passed in via a function.

the data is:
[image]

and my chart looks like:
[image]

and my path/dots being generated look like:
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is the issue? You have dates in your dataSet and you would need to have a timeScale applied to get actual X,Y coordinates

Comment: Could you include your data instead of the img?

Comment: @MikeTung I thought Ordinal scales would work, no?

Comment: @mahan yep, one sec. Edited it

Comment: Need some clarification: 1. Are you trying to plot 1 line using `lineData[0]` (array of 12 numbers) and 12 circles using `lineData[1]` (array of 12 numbers)? 2. Or are you trying to plot 2 lines based on `lineData[0]` and `lineData[1]` and circles accordingly? (considering the months in `lineData[2]` as **xAxis** in both of the above cases). That's because you're binding `lineData` to the circles along with calling the `.attr('d', line)` for the circles which is confusing.

Comment: @Shashank  trying to plot 1 line using lineData[0] (array of 12 numbers)

Eventually, using the 2nd array to plot a second line (just trying to get the first line to work)

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing points:

1. Important: Ideally you should be using a [d3 time scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleTime) as you're looking to plot a line based on months. But an ordinal scale would work too. I'm guessing you're looking for [d3.scaleBand](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleBand) here.

> Band scales are like ordinal scales except the output range is continuous and numeric.

Why not use `d3.scaleOrdinal`? Here's an example:

```js
let lineData = [
    [4, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 52, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1], 
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
  ]

        let xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(lineData[2])
            .domain(lineData[0]);
            
    console.log('domain is: ' + xScale.domain());
    console.log('range is: ' + xScale.range());
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

You see how the repeated values get mapped onto the months which wouldn't help in your case and so the `d3.scaleBand()` (you could also play around with using `d3.scalePoint`. [Read more about it in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426884/creating-a-categorical-line-chart-in-d3-js-v4#answer-41427187)

2. Using the above band scale, the domain you'd set would be the `lineData[2]` the following way:

   ```
   xScale = d3.scaleBand().domain(lineData[2])
   ```
3. Transforms weren't being applied to the `line` and the `circles`. So I appended `<g>` containers to contain the lines and circles respectively and transformed these group elements. For example:

   ```
   var dots = lineChart.append('g')
       .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");
   ```

**The solution below just answers this specific question on appending the first line to the chart. As you mentioned in the comments that you'd eventually work on adding the second element as another line, the `path` selection would change**

```js
let lineData = [
    [4, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 52, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1], 
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
    ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"]
  ]
        // set dimensions of the line chart
        let width = 393,
            height = 285;


        // set the scales
        let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()    
            .domain([0, 52])
            .range([height - 40 , 0]);

        let xScale = d3.scaleBand().domain(lineData[2])
            .rangeRound([0, width - 40]);

        // create the line
        let line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d, i) { 
             return xScale(lineData[2][i]) + xScale.bandwidth()/2; 
            })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(d); });

        // create svg container
        let lineChart = d3.select('body')
            .append("svg")
            .attr("viewbox", "0 60 960 600")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class", "line-chart")

    var lineG = lineChart.append('g')
         .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");
          
        lineG.append("path")
            .data(lineData)
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "rebeccapurple")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)

   var dots = lineChart.append('g')
         .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");
        dots.selectAll("dot")
            .data(lineData[0])
            .enter()
            .append("circle").classed('dot', true)
            .attr("r", 3.5)
            .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(lineData[2][i]) + xScale.bandwidth()/2})
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d)})
            .attr("fill", "rebeccapurple")

        lineChart.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20, 245)")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))

        lineChart.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Suggestion: It's not a good practice to set a domain to a static value as you do for `yScale` [0,52]. Try using [d3.extent](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent) or [d3.min](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#min) methods.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** As you're trying to use `d3.scalePoint`, you're making a minor mistake in choosing the xScale value in the `line` function and for the circles. You'd need to choose `categories[i]` in the line fn as following:

```
.x(function(d, i) { 
     return xScale(categories[i]); 
 })
```

**Updated snippet using d3.scalePoint**

```js
let data = {
    'New': [4, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4, 52, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1], 
    'Terminated': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
  };
  let categories = ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"];
  
            let lineData = [data.New, data.Terminated, categories];

        
            // set dimensions of the line chart
            let width = 393,
                height = 285;

            // set the scales
            let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()    
                .domain([0, 60]).nice()
                .range([height - 40 , 0]);
        
            let xScale = d3.scalePoint()
                .domain(lineData[2].map(function(d, i) { return d; }))
                .range([0, width - 40]);
        
            // create the line
            let line = d3.line()
                .x(function(d, i) { 
                 return xScale(categories[i]); 
                })
                .y(function(d) { return yScale(d); });
        
            // create svg container
            let lineChart = d3.select('body')
                .append("svg")
                .attr("viewbox", "0 60 960 600")
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("class", "line-chart")

    var lineG = lineChart.append('g')
         .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");
            lineG.append("path")
                .datum(lineData)
                .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d[0]); })
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "rebeccapurple")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
          
            lineChart.selectAll("dot")
                .data(lineData[0])
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)")
                .attr("r", 3.5)
                .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(categories[i])})
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d)})
                .attr("fill", "rebeccapurple")
        
            lineChart.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(20, 245)")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))

        
            lineChart.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps too.

Comment: This is very helpful! A couple things - Time scale returned some really weird results. I wanted to stick with ordinal because it's a string; however; I found scalePoint did exactly what I needed! I tried making some of the changes, but it broke the graph. With some of the changes I made, now the graph looks better, but I'm still seeing NaN values for some of the data. You can see my updated code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RevxYG?editors=0010. I'll add this link and the updated image to my OP

Comment: this is actually perfect, I went your route instead of scalePoint. Thanks again!

Comment: @Almost_Ashleigh Updated the post with an implementation using `d3.scalePoint` (if you're still interested in knowing how that'd work out). Glad I could help! :)